# Stabilizer of probability measure on projective space

Tags: probability-theory, lie-groups, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, lattices-in-lie-groups

I'm reading notes on Lattices on Lie groups (in French:
[Réseaux des groupes de Lie](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebenoist/prepubli/08m2p6ch1a13.pdf)) by Yves Benoist and I have some
troubles to understand some aspects on the setting & proof of the
**Lemma 7.3** (due to Furstenberg) on page 60.

> Let $k= \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ or a finite
> extension of $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $p$ prime. Let $E:=k^d$ be
> a vector space and $\mathbb{P}(E)$ the associated projective space,
> $\operatorname{PGL}(E)$ the group of projective transformations
> on $\mathbb{P}(E)$ and $\nu$ a probability measure on
> $\mathbb{P}(E)$.

Let $S:= \{ g \in \operatorname{PGL}(E) \ \vert \ g_* \nu = \nu \} $.

(recall $ g_* \nu $ is the push-forward or image measure with respect
automorphism $g: \mathbb{P}(E) \to \mathbb{P}(E)$)

Questions:

**1)** In the notes there is not a word said about the $\sigma$-algebra
with which the projective space $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is endowed which allows
to consider a (probability) $\nu$.
In most cases when dealing with measures on affine space $k^d$
without making any comment on the underlying $\sigma$-algebra,
one uses in silence the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra, a kind of canonical
$\sigma$-algebra on affine spaces.

Is there any type of "canonical" $\sigma$-algebra for
projective spaces which is in most cases used when one is
discussing measures on projective spaces without mentioning
by name the underlying $\sigma$-algebra? So is there a kind of
standard $\sigma$-algebra for projective spaces known as a sort of
pendant to the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra for affine spaces?

**2)** At the beginning of the proof of the Lemma there is remarked that it's rather
obvious that the stabilizer $S:= \{ g \in \operatorname{PGL}(E) \ \vert \ g_* \nu = \nu \} $
of probability measure $\nu$
is a closed subspace in $\operatorname{PGL}(E)$.

Why that's the case? I assume that the topology on
$\operatorname{PGL}(E)$ is the quotient topology induced
from $\operatorname{GL}(E) \subset \operatorname{End}(E) \cong k^{d^2}$.

It is known that if in general a topological group $G$ acts continuously
on a topological space $S$ by continuous map
$a: G \times S \to S$, then any stabilizer is closed.
But here we consider the "stabilization" of a measure und
there is no standard way I know to endow the "space of meausures"
on $\mathbb{P}(E)$ with continuous $\operatorname{PGL}(E)$-action.

How the closedness of
$S= \{ g \in \operatorname{PGL}(E) \ \vert \ g_* \nu = \nu \} $
can be deduced? I not see the exact reason why that's really clair at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** The canonical projection $\pi:E\setminus0\to \mathbb{P}(E)$ is a (topological) quotient map; the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is the associated Borel $\sigma$-algebra (in your situation, and in general if $\sigma$-algebras are not mentioned). By an argument similar to that discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4348985/169085 this is the same thing as saying $B\subseteq \mathbb{P}(E)$ is measurable iff $\pi^{-1}(B)\subseteq E\setminus0$ is Borel measurable.

**2)** Note that $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is a compact metric space. Consequently the space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{P}(E))$ of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is compact w/r/t the weakstar topology. Further, the action $\mathbb{P}\text{GL}(E)\curvearrowright \mathbb{P}(E)$ is by homeomorphisms, so the action $\mathbb{P}\text{GL}(E)\curvearrowright \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{P}(E)), g\curvearrowright \mu=g_\ast(\mu)$ is by affine homeomorphisms. (You are correct to assume $\mathbb{P}\text{GL}(E)$ to be endowed with the quotient topology). Now you can use the general statement about stabilizers of topological actions, or alternatively you can take $g_n\to g$ and argue that if $(g_n)_\ast(\nu)=\nu$, then $g_\ast(\nu)=\nu$ also. Of course, the stabilizer is not only a closed subspace; it's a closed subgroup.

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! one remark: you use the statement that if $S$ is a *compact metric space*, then the space $\mathcal{M}(S)$ of Borel probability measures on $S$ is *compact* wrt weak^* topology. could you give a reference for the proof of this statement. I should admit that I have never saw it before

Comment: @user7391733 I'm glad it was useful. Regarding the compactness of $\mathcal{M}(S)$, Parthasarathy's book Probability Measures on Metric Spaces is the standard reference (see Thm.6.4 on p.45 for the particular statement). Introductory books on ergodic theory (Walters, Einsiedler-Ward, Brin-Stuck, Katok-Hasselblatt ...)  would contain a proof as well.